# Python - Performing different tasks based input() data-type

Tags: python, input, types, while-loop, continue

***Edit***:
This post differs from [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) because I do not end the loop based on data type of the response. Both strings and integers are valid. The loop should only kick-back if the two entries are ***different*** data types.

I'm trying to collect either two words, or two integers via input(). **If both values are integers** I want to calculate `answer1**answer2.` **If both are non-integers**, I want to concatenate the strings. Finally, **if the data-types do not match**, I want to send the user to the beginning to enter two new values.

Here's my attempt. I apologize in advance for what you're about to see.

```
## collect first value
print("Please type a word or an integer:")
answer1 = input()

## check for blanks
if answer1 == "":
    print("Blank space detected. Please retry.")
    answer1 = input()

## collect second value
print("Please type another word or integer:")
answer2 = input()

## check for blanks
if answer2 == "":
    print("Blank space detected. Please retry.")
    answer2 = input()

## define test for integer status
def containsInt(intTest):
    try: 
        int(intTest)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass

## check for matching data types and produce final value
if containsInt(answer1) == True:
    containsInt(answer2)
    if containsInt(answer2) == True:
        finalInt = (int(answer1))**(int(answer2))
        print("\n")
        print(finalInt)
    else:
        print("Sorry, the data types must match - both words or integers.")
        continue
else:
    containsInt(answer2)
    if containsInt(answer2) !=True:
        print("\n")
        print(answer1 + answer2)
    else:
        print("Sorry, the data types must match - both words or integers.")
        continue
```

I tried to use "continue" to get it to go back to the beginning, but it becomes angry at me. You can probably tell I'm a complete newb, and this is my first post. Please don't rip on me too hard. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
while True:
    answer1 = input("Please type a word or an integer:")

    # check for blanks
    while answer1 == "":
        answer1 = input("Blank space detected. Please retry.")

    try:
        answer1 = int(answer1)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    answer2 = input("Please type another word or integer:")

    # check for blanks
    while answer2 == "":
        answer2 = input("Blank space detected. Please retry.")

    try:
        answer2 = int(answer2)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if type(answer1) == type(answer2):
        if type(answer1) == str:
            print(answer1 + answer2)
            break
        elif type(answer1) == int:
            print(answer1**answer2)
            break
    else:
        print(f"Sorry, the data types of '{answer1}' and '{answer2}' do not match.")
        continue
```

Do note that if you input a number like `1.5` it will be treated as a string.
so the inputs `1.5` and `a` will result in `1.5a`

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` only works for loops, that is `for` and `while`. You are trying to use `continue` outside of a loop and that is why Python does not like it.

One thing you could do is check if the data types match and then do things based on that:

```py
if type(answer1) == type(answer2):
    if isinstance(answer1, str):
        # do string stuff
    elif isinstance(answer1, int) or isinstance(answer1, float):
        # do calculations
    else:
        # types match but are not strings or numbers
else:
    # types don't match, react accordingly
```

By default Python treats inputs as `string`s, so even if give a number to the input, it will be of type `string`. You can work through this in many ways, one of which is that you e.g. *attempt* to transform the input to a number. `float` works better than `int` in this case, since otherwise you could not handle decimals well. Example:

```py
answer1 = input()
try:
    answer1 = float(answer)
except:
    pass
```

What this does is that you attempt to transform the string-by-default input into a floating point number, and if that does not work, then it stays as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Unfortunately, this is telling me that everything matches. I used ```print(type(answer1))``` and ```print(type(answer2))``` to determine that, even when I type in an integer into the input() it is treating it as a string.

Comment: I have edited my answer to help you with this type problem.